# How can i have more free memory on pytorch?

Tags: python, memory, amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu

I'm having a issue when training my model on my GPU. The free space i have is very small compared to the total capacity.

PS : I'm using a EC2 instance to run my code and my database is composed of 1920x1080 images

```
(GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 1.51 GiB already allocated; 497.75 MiB free; 1.53 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Another thing is that the free memory seems to grow with the batch-size i use.
For example :

-for `batch_size = 4` I get :   `(GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 1.87 GiB already allocated; 123.75 MiB free; 1.90 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`

-for `batch_size = 8` I get :   `(GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 1.87 GiB already allocated; 797.75 MiB free; 1.90 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`

And here you have my main :

```
device = Trainer.define_working_device()

    train_data_dir = '../../asset/train'
    test_data_dir = '../../asset/test'
    batch_size = 4

    pre_trained_model = Resnet_model.load_pretrained_resnet18()

    pre_trained_model = pre_trained_model.to(device)

    train_data = Load_function.load_and_normalized_data(train_data_dir, batch_size)
    test_data = Load_function.load_and_normalized_data(test_data_dir, batch_size)

    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    pre_trained_model = Trainer.train_model(pre_trained_model, train_data, test_data, device, 25)
```

And here you have the function i used :

```
def train_model(model, train_data, test_data, device, num_epochs):
    plt.ion()
    since = time.time()

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

    train_loss_history = []
    train_accuracy_history = []

    test_loss_history = []
    test_accuracy_history = []

    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        train_running_loss = 0.0
        train_running_corrects = 0

        test_running_loss = 0.0
        test_running_corrects = 0.0

        train_data_size = len(train_data)
        test_data_size = len(test_data)

        # Iterate over train data.
        for i, data_train in enumerate(train_data, 0):
            model.train()
            inputs, labels = data_train

            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(inputs)

            _, train_preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            # backward + optimize only if in training phase
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # statistics
            train_running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            train_running_corrects += torch.sum(train_preds == labels.data)

        del inputs
        del labels

        for i, data_test in enumerate(test_data, 0):
            model.eval()
            test_inputs, test_labels = data_test

            test_inputs = test_inputs.to(device)
            test_labels = test_labels.to(device)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(test_inputs)

            _, test_preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, test_labels)

            # statistics
            test_running_loss += loss.item() * test_inputs.size(0)
            test_running_corrects += torch.sum(test_preds == test_labels.data)

        del test_inputs
        del test_labels

        scheduler.step()

        train_epoch_loss = train_running_loss / train_data_size
        train_epoch_acc = train_running_corrects.double() / train_data_size

        test_epoch_loss = test_running_loss / test_data_size
        test_epoch_acc = test_running_corrects.double() / test_data_size

        train_loss_history.append(train_epoch_loss)
        train_accuracy_history.append(train_epoch_acc)

        test_loss_history.append(test_epoch_loss)
        test_accuracy_history.append(test_epoch_acc)

        """
        plt.close()

        plt.plot(test_loss_history)
        plt.plot(train_loss_history)
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(test_accuracy_history)
        plt.plot(train_accuracy_history)
        plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
        plt.show()
"""
        print('Train data : Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_acc))
        print('-' * 5)
        print('Test data : Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(test_epoch_loss, test_epoch_acc))

    plt.imsave('../results/accuracy.png', test_accuracy_history)
    plt.imsave('../results/loss.png', test_loss_history)

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
        time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    print('Finished Training')
    return model
```

```
def define_working_device():
    logging.info(torch.__version__)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda:0")  # you can continue going on here, like cuda:1 cuda:2....etc.
        print(device)
        print("Running on the GPU")
        logging.info("Running on the GPU")
        return device
    else:
        device = torch.device("cpu")
        print("Running on the CPU")
        logging.info("Running on the CPU")
        return device
```

```
def load_pretrained_resnet18():
    net = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    logging.info("Model successfully loaded")
    num_features = net.fc.in_features
    net.fc = nn.Linear(num_features, 2)
    return net
```

If someone can help me, thanks !!

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Your GPU has 14.76GiB in total. Can you try increasing your batch size drastically? Say, set batch size as 128 or something. Also, if you can add some minimal code, that would be helpful? :)

Comment: The error means that it does not fit in your GPU. These memory values are somewhat tricky to interpret. You'll have to reduce batch size.

Comment: Hi @GautamSreekumar, I've updated my post if you wanna check but i have the same issue when scalling up the batch size.

Comment: Hello @Berriel, the batch size i'm using on this 14Go GPU is the same i used on my personal GPU which is only 4Go. I thought that 14Go would be enough to increase the batch size even if the memory repartition isn't well organized in the GPU.

Comment: @KévinPinson I didn't understand... so, this batch size fits in your 4GB gpu and doesn't fit in the 14GB gpu? Have you tried with a smaller batch size as suggested? This OOM error is quite clear.

Comment: @Berriel yes and obviusly it works but the point i wanted to make is that i should have way more free space in my GPU

Comment: @KévinPinson then what is the batch size that fits and how much of the gpu memory it takes?

Comment: @Berriel the max batch size that fit is 4 and it takes 138 Mb of the gpu memory

Comment: 138 Mb of gpu memory seems like very little for a ResNet18 with this batch size. How are you measuring that? Does this OOM error happens at the very first batch or after some time?